# Chrome icon looking pale

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am new to JS and web framework - I am trying to work with Chrome instance from Puppeteer.

The instance always opens up in a "pale looking Chrome icon" like this:
[image]

I suppressed "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" with `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation']` but to no avail.

My questions are following -

- What exactly is this instance differnet from the regular [image]?
- Is there any workaround so that new instance of [image] opens up?
- Is there any particular situations I should rather stick to [image] instead of [image]?

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
        args: ['--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--mute-audio',
        '--disable-web-security']
    });
```

Comment: That's the [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) icon. See [What's the difference between Google Chrome and/or Chromium? What are the advantages/disadvantages to each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6253/whats-the-difference-between-google-chrome-and-or-chromium-what-are-the-advant)